# Can I create a data frame that has data frame as its elements? (Pyspark using sqlContext)

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have 15k small files. After processing, each file generates three Data frames object: v, vT and e. I want to store all this three data frames of all 15k files into one data frame object(Let's call it combo) and write to disk so that next time I just read it once rather than 15k times. Besides, I can also convert this combo to RDD and apply map function to 15k records at once. This would make full use of the CPU.

But currently my implementation is I write v, vT and e into one folder(per file per folder. In total, 15k folders). In each folder, there are three folders for v, vT and e separately. Now I have to read each 15k times for all the files (technically I need to read 15k * 3 = 45k times). When I apply certain algorithms on those files, I simply use a **for** loop to apply algorithms on them one by one. Not very smart I know

So I came up with an idea which is to store v, vT and e of the 15k files into a list called combo and then create a single data frame, combo_df. By convert combo_df to RDD, I can use map function to apply a user-defined function on all 15k at a time.

The code is as follows, for each file:

```
v = sqlContext.createDataFrame(uri, 
                                ['id', 'URI', 'flag'])
vT = sqlContext.createDataFrame(vertex, 
                               ['id', 'URI_ID_FK', 'Vertex_Type_URI_ID_FK'])
e = sqlContext.createDataFrame(edge, 
                                ['src', 'dst', 'Relation_Type_URI_ID_FK'])
```

uri, vertex and edge are three lists object extracted from each file.

Store all v, vT and e of the 15k files into a single list combo

```
combo = [[v1, vT2, e3],...,[vN, vTN, eN]] (pseudo-code)
```

I want to create a data frame(combo_df) using combo

```
combo_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(combo, ['v', 'vT', 'e'])
```

At this point, I got an error:

> AssertionError: dataType should be DataType

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I create a data frame that has data frame as its elements?

You cannot. Just write each `DataFrame` separately.

Comment: I have 15k files. In such case, I will have to create 45k files. This files are pretty small like 100kb to 300kb. So I need to find a way to combine all them into one dataframe meaning giving me 15k file, I give you one data frame back.

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me like you want to keep the three dataframes separate because of their structure. Instead of creating three distinct dataframes from reading each file you should consider keeping only one and reorganizing the columns into `structType()` for **nested dataframes**. You'll end up with a schema like this:

```py
    root
     |-- v: struct (nullable = false)
     |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- URI: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- flag: string (nullable = true)
     |-- vT: struct (nullable = false)
     |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- URI_ID_FK: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- Vertex_Type_URI_ID_FK: string (nullable = true)
     |-- e: struct (nullable = false)
     |    |-- src: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- dst: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- Relation_Type_URI_ID_FK: string (nullable = true)
```

The function for it is

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This could be a solution. Another problem I have is how can I combine all those 15k files' data frames together and apply map function on them at once. The reason I want to do this is because, right now I basically used a for loop to loop through them. In such case, the CPU usage is very low. Surprisingly, Spark client mode(driver and work on one single processor) is much faster than cluster mode(one for driver, two for workers). I am so confused.

Comment: If you iterate in a loop you lose the distributed aspect of spark. You can read all the files in one setting by specifying the parent directory as a path instead of a the file path.